Did a rear brake job, rotors pads + calipers. Carefully bedded in brakes, but still, it's now shaking when braking. Could it be overly tight lug nuts?
Did everything to the letter but car still shakes when brake is applied. Could over- tightening the lug nuts have caused it?
If not that, what else could it be?

What about the front end? Most braking is done by the front end (biased about 65%/35% front to rear). If you're getting shaking when braking, it's probably from the front.

Thanks, will check out the front.
